# HTC Vive to Baxter co-ordinate system

Tags: ros, htc-vive

I'm trying to map HTC Vive controllers to Baxter's arms through ROS.

So I've got scripts working for getting controller data & have successfully mapped position (x, y, z) to control the robot's arms according the the R-H rule I found through: http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html

However, I'm having lots of trouble with orientation. Specifically, I am not sure how orientation of Baxter's co-ordinate frame is relative to the HTC controller's. Right now I've got it mapped as follow: rot.z, rot.y, rot.x= rot.y, -rot.x, -rot.z

It seemed to be 'correct' mapping of orientation- e.g. when I tilt up or pan left/right, the tf shows correct movement. I noticed that Baxter's end effectors co-ordinate system appears to be different to that of ROS. So now, whenever I hold the controller upright, Baxter's end-effector points backwards, rather than forwards. Any idea on how to correct this?

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2okMp.jpg) are some pictures to explain my issue. The tf in Rviz shows Baxter's end effector pointing in the direction the blue axis (Z), whereas my controller would be pointing in the red axis (X)... so I'm not sure if this is the problem. If anyone has successfully mapped HTC controllers to a Baxter machine before, I'd be very appreciative of any feedback!